# how to notify of CKEditor text changes (send to owner window)

Tags: ckeditor

How to notify owner document of changes in CKEditor? I mean when I type sth, delete, paste, undo/redo (every event which changes text) I need to set a flag in window containing CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Use [editor#change](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) event (since 4.2). [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/xfvrA/).

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    on: {
        change: function( evt ) {
            console.log( evt ); 
        }
    }
} );
```